# What is a similar word to "comprehensive" that doesn't suggest absolutely everything will be covered?

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

I'm putting together a proposal for a website and one of the things that we're providing is a knowledge base for users to find solutions to their problems.

I'd like to imply that the KB will have a lot of information in it, but don't want to suggest that it'll cover everything the user could ever need, as **comprehensive** does. **Vast** also feels like it's implying that the KB will be ... well, vast, which it won't necessarily.

Is there a more suitable word?

Comment: How about *significant*? That's often used as a sort of soft antonym to *trivial*.

Comment: I think that's an answer rather than a comment there!

Comment: See http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/comprehensive?s=t

Comment: Possibly "detailed", although that implies more depth than breadth.

Comment: It's probably worth pointing out that _comprehensive_ doesn't mean _everything_, it means _everything, or much, or most, or a large proportion of_. see http://www.thefreedictionary.com/comprehensive

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[Extensive](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/extensive) may suggest a wide but not full coverage:

> - having wide or considerable extent, *extensive reading*. (M-W)

Comment: I think I'll go with this; as mentioned in comments on Sobrique's answer it may be redundant anyhow, but I'm OK with that in this situation

Comment: Similar but stronger: Exhaustive?

Comment: @DavidPugh: I'm -1 on Exhausive.  It implies you've totally exhausted the problem space, that you cover everything under the sun.

Comment: @Kevin: Fair cop, guv. I'd forgotten or filtered out the negative in Joe's question. I shall give to charity.

Answer (score 3):

There are two aspects or dimensions when describing how much knowledge or information is present somewhere: *breadth* and *depth*. Breadth refers to the extent of the *topics covered*; depth refers to the thoroughness with which *each topic* is treated.

"Vast", to me, primarily implies *breadth*, while "comprehensive" implies both.

So I would recommend first determining whether you want to emphasize the *breadth*, *depth*, or *both* of the KB, and then just...use one or both of those words. My instinct is that **"broad"** is probably the word you should pick--it is simple and clear.

Answer (score 1):

[Encyclopedic](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/encyclopedic):

> dealing with or knowing a subject thoroughly or completely

Comment: That also feels a bit too much like it's promising a fully definitive KB - I'm more angling for a sort of "most of your problems will be solved here" kind of word

Comment: Surely that's already implicit in 'knowedgebase'?

Comment: This is a fair point. It's certainly possible that I just don't need a qualifying word; marketing-speak sometimes makes you forget that you already have a word saying that thing :P

Answer (score 0):

"While *not definitive*, the knowledge base provides a valuable resource for users."

definitive as in:

> most reliable or complete, as of a text, author, criticism, study, or
>   the like

Comment: Extensive was already suggested.

Comment: The key words are "not definitive". I can remove the use of the word extensive though.

Comment: Oh, I see now. Definitiveness carries the idea of officialness and finality I think - but there are lots of official and final documents which are not fully comprehensive.

Comment: @curiousdannii Good point.

Answer (score -1):

> **vo·lu·mi·nous**
>
> 3 a :  having or marked by great volume :  bulky, large, swelling
>   specifically :  full
>
> b :  seeming to fill a large indefinite space
>
> c :  numerous
>
> 4 a :  filling or capable of filling a large volume or several volumes
>
> Merriam-Webster Unabridged Dictionary

Answer (score -1):

How about *a wealth of information*?